# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException when setting a ListView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

This is the full stacktrace i get when i execute this snippet of code:

```
        ArrayList<String> errorsList = generateErrorList();
        ListView myListView = (ListView) myActivity.findViewById(R.id.errorConfList);
        ArrayAdapter<String> errorAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(myActivity.getApplicationContext(), R.id.errorConfList, errorsList);
        myListView.setAdapter(errorAdapter);
        errorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**Logcat**

```
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0a007e type #0x12 is not valid
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2136)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:865)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2465)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1775)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:678)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:739)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1614)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2300)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13862)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13862)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13862)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1585)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13862)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13862)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13862)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13862)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1992)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1813)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4481)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
11-22 15:58:49.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7422):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The XML of my android layout has:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/errorConfList"
    android:background="#44FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView1" >
</ListView>
```

I don't get why this error appears. Any hint?

Comment: Are you sure that you set the right contentView before casting your ListView ? Looks like you loaded the wrong layout.

Comment: your second parameter to the arrayadapter is supposed to be a layout, not an id, and refers to the row, not the list.

Comment: @njzk2 why not an answer?

Comment: @codeMagic : because at first I wanted to comment "read the doc"

Answer (score 2):

I think that your problem is in this line:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> errorAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(myActivity.getApplicationContext(), 
                R.id.errorConfList, errorsList);
```

insted of `R.id.errorConfList` you need to use the frameworks simple list item :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> errorAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(myActivity.getApplicationContext(), 
                R.layout.simple_list_item_1, errorsList);
```

i hope it helped

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

change to

```
ArrayAdapter<String> errorAdapter =
                    new ArrayAdapter<String>(myActivity.getApplicationContext(), 
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, errorsList);
```

follow tutorials

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

for customized list row

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/